# Diferença de um mesmo código com e sem o for()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, for

Estou montando um código jQuery com o dateTimePicker Bootstrap.

Estou tentou um problema que é o seguinte: quando eu faço de uma maneira mais extensa funciona perfeitamente, porém quando eu tento fazer de uma forma mais simplificada, mais dinâmica, não funciona.

Como está funcionando:

```
        $("#dt_in0").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br" });
        $("#dt_fim0").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br", useCurrent: false });

        $("#dt_in0").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $("#dt_fim0").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#dt_fim0").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $("#dt_in0").data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });

        $("#hr_in0").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
        $("#hr_fim0").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });

        $("#dt_in1").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br" });
        $("#dt_fim1").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br", useCurrent: false });

        $("#dt_in1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $("#dt_fim1").data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#dt_fim1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $("#dt_in1").data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });

        $("#hr_in1").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
        $("#hr_fim1").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
```

Maneira dinâmica e que não está funcionando corretamente:

```
    for (x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
            var di = ("#dt_in" + x).toString();
            var df = ("#dt_fim" + x).toString();
            var hi = ("#hr_in" + x).toString();
            var hf = ("#hr_fim" + x).toString();

            $(di).datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br" });
            $(df).datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br", useCurrent: false });

            $(di).on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $(df).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
            $(df).on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $(di).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            });

            $(hi).datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
            $(hf).datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
    }
```

O problema que estou tendo é neste `change`, que não está definindo a data máxima e mínima corretamente.

Há alguma diferença nos meus códigos que poderia estar causando isso? Pois pra mim estou gerando por final o mesmo código, de forma diferente e mais dinâmica, mas o resultado era pra ser o mesmo.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Troque esse `for` por [isto](https://jsfiddle.net/pjhtqsnd/) e veja se funciona.

Comment: @Sam, funcionou o seu código, mas poderia me explicá-lo? não entendi bem oque foi que você fez

Comment: Vou postar uma resposta explicando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar `for` com seletores no jQuery não faz muito sentido porque o jQuery tem a flexibilidade de alcançar vários ou todos os elementos de uma coleção, coisa que o JavaScript puro geralmente não faz. Por exemplo, se eu quiser aplicar `display: none` em todos os elementos da classe `.btn`:

**Com jQuery:**

```
$(".btn").hide();
```

**Com JS puro:**

```
const btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for(let x=0; x < btn.length; x++){
   btn[x].style.display = "none";
}
```

Com isso, você pode alcançar todos os elementos do seu código usando o seletor apropriado, que podem ser inúmeros, dependendo da situação. No seu caso, poderia pegar pelos id's ou de outra forma dependendo da estrutura do seu HTML. Mas vou colocar um exemplo pegando pelo `id`, já que eles são quase iguais, diferenciando apenas pelo número no final:

```
$("[id^='dt_in']").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br" });
$("[id^='dt_fim']").datetimepicker({ format: "DD/MM/YYYY", locale: "pt-br", useCurrent: false });

$("[id^='dt_in']").on("dp.change", function () {
    $("#dt_fim"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
$("[id^='dt_fim']").on("dp.change", function () {
    $("#dt_in"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});

$("[id^='hr_in']").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
$("[id^='hr_fim']").datetimepicker({ format: "HH:mm", locale: "pt-br" });
```

Por exemplo, o seletor `[id^='dt_in']` irá pegar todos os elementos que possuem o id começando com `dt_in`, ou seja `dt_in0`, `dt_in1`, `dt_in2` etc. Os sinais `^=` significa que o atributo deve começar pela string especificada, no caso, "dt_in".

Na função do evento `dp.change` usei o seletor:

```
"#dt_in"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')
```

Significa que irá pegar o elemento que possui o id `#dt_in` + a parte numérica do elemento que chamou o evento. Por exemplo:

```
     elemento que chamou o evento
        ↓
$("[id^='dt_fim']").on("dp.change", function () {
    $("#dt_in"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

Se o elemento que chamou o evento tiver o id `dt_fim1`, o replace irá retirar tudo o que não for número do id, ou seja, restando apenas o número `1`, com a expressão regular:

```
/[^\d]/g
```

O `[]` significa "conjunto de caracteres". O sinal `^` significa que irá pegar tudo que não for número, representado pelo `\d`, e o `g` (de *global*) quer dizer que irá pegar todas as ocorrências.

Com isso, se o elemento que chamou o evento for `#dt_fim1`, o `$("#dt_in"+this.id.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''))` será o mesmo que `$("#dt_in1")`.